# how to display exception message in some language alway

Tags: android, exception

how to get the exception message in english alway or other language

```
private static String getMsgLocale(String str){
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(str)){
        return "";
    }
    String err =  String.format(JAPAN,str);

    return err;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloud Translation in this scenario, See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/)
Also, check out this awesome [article](https://medium.com/@yeksancansu/how-to-use-google-translate-api-in-android-studio-projects-7f09cae320c7)